# Error after adding a new column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i added a new column to a table using the follwing:

```
ALTER TABLE Parit
ADD test nvarchar(50)
```

when then i try to refer to the table it shows the colmun but i get a red dotted line under
the column name sayin invaild column name

Comment: in the ssms you can press Ctrl+Shift+R to update the IntelliSense

Comment: thank you it works , but when i try to update i get the following : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test' to data type int.

Comment: i am doing thw following : 
UPDATE Parit
set [test_column] = RIGHT(Parit.[test_column],LEN(Parit.[test_column]-1))

Comment: You tried to run `LEN([test_column]-1)` instead of `LEN([test_column])-1`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error.

Just IntelliSense needs to be updated. You can update IntelliSense by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + R`

Comment: it works , but now when i try to update i get the following: 
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test' to data type int.

Comment: What is the actual data type of the new column and your update command?

Comment: i am doing thw following : 
UPDATE Parit
set [test_column] = RIGHT(Parit.[test_column],LEN(Parit.[test_column]-1))

Comment: they are all nvarchar

Comment: UPDATE Parit set [test_column] = RIGHT(Parit.[test_column],LEN(Parit.[test_column])-1)

Comment: Try my last comment. -1 must be out of LEN function.